# Google Visualizations: Where does JS execution begin again after drawing charts?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling, google-visualization

A small project using Google Visualizations, https://jsfiddle.net/brisray/qsgewt2d/ - works as far as I have it, but I have a question about it.

Once the graphs are drawn, I assumed that control would pass back to "mainFunction".  This is a function that loops through the object array I made creating the queries, then calls other functions that draws the tables and charts. I was hoping to add more code to that function to call other functions for other things I want to do.

What I find is that it doesn't work that way. A simple JS alert AFTER the loop shows none of the drawing is done until the alert is acknowledged.

Am I missing something? Perhaps an event handler that's triggered after the last of the array is processed and the last of the initial graphs drawn? Something to do with the asynchronous natures of the drawing.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the code and the way I've written it?

Whatever is happening, I cannot see it, so would appreciate some help.

Ray

```
var SCOB_metrics = (function() {

  // Create the object array that is global to the namespace
  var graphArray = [];
  // Create objects and push them to the array
  // Object properties are: ID, sheet, GID, datatable, graphtype, rotated 

  createObject('MSDC', '1RCZiWWsEKPs6-1ULXeHjWmaXUEHCaRPtKT9U_6FzCJ4', '1835225366', 'MSDC_data', 'Column', false);
  createObject('StudentPop', '1RCZiWWsEKPs6-1ULXeHjWmaXUEHCaRPtKT9U_6FzCJ4', '3256521', 'StudentPop_data', 'Column', false);
  createObject('EnrolTrends', '1RCZiWWsEKPs6-1ULXeHjWmaXUEHCaRPtKT9U_6FzCJ4', '1037635451', 'EnrolTrends_data', 'Column', false);

  google.charts.load('current');
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(mainFunction);

  function mainFunction() {
    for (i = 0; i < graphArray.length; i++) {
      makeQuery(graphArray[i]);
    }
    // Now everthing is drawn, set up the listener for the drawingArea div
    // so that the graphs can be updated if needed
    var theParent = document.querySelector("#drawingArea");
    theParent.addEventListener("change", whichDrop, false);
  }

  function makeQuery(myObject) {
    // Create the querystring and send it 
    var queryStr = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + myObject.sheet + "/gviz/tq?gid=" + myObject.GID + "&headers=1";
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryStr);
    /* You can't send a variable though the normal query.send method
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    so do this */
    query.send(function(response) {
      visuals(response, myObject);
    });
  }

  function whichDrop(e) {
    // Find which dropdown was changed, get it's value, find the index of the graphArray.ID it belongs to and redraw the graph
    if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
      var changedItem = e.target.id;
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    var findID = changedItem.substr(0, changedItem.length - 4);
    arrayIndex = graphArray.findIndex(x => x.ID == findID);
    var e = document.getElementById(changedItem);
    var chosenGraph = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    graphArray[arrayIndex].graphtype = chosenGraph;
    drawGraphs(graphArray[arrayIndex]);
  }

  function visuals(response, myObject) {
    // Create the data table and draw both the table and graph
    myObject.datatable = response.getDataTable();
    drawTables(myObject);
    drawGraphs(myObject);
  }

  function drawTables(myObject) {
    // Draw the table
    var tableArea = myObject.ID + "_table_div";
    var cssClassNames = {
      'headerRow': 'header-css',
      'headerCell': 'border-css'
    };
    theTables = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'Table',
      containerId: tableArea,
      dataTable: myObject.datatable,
      options: {
        'allowHtml': true,
        'cssClassNames': cssClassNames
      }
    });
    theTables.draw();
  }

  function drawGraphs(myObject) {
    // Draw the graph
    var graphArea = myObject.ID + "_graph_div";
    var chartType = myObject.graphtype + "Chart";
    theGraphs = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: chartType,
      containerId: graphArea,
      dataTable: myObject.datatable,
      // May have to use IF or SWITCH statements depending on chartType
      options: {
        height: 400,
        hAxis: {
          maxTextLines: 4, // maximum number of lines to wrap to
          maxAlternation: 4, // maximum layers of labels (setting this higher than 1 allows labels to stack over/under each other)
          minTextSpacing: 1, // minimum space in pixels between adjacent labels
        },
        textStyle: {
          fontSize: 9
        }
      }
    });
    theGraphs.draw();
  }

  function transposeDataTable(myObject) {
    // Transpose the datatable 
    dataTable = myObject.datatable;
    // Toggle rotated boolean
    myObject.rotated = !myObject.rotated;
    // Rotate the datatable
    var rows = []; //the row tip becomes the column header and the rest become
    for (var rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); rowIdx++) {
      var rowData = [];
      for (var colIdx = 0; colIdx < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); colIdx++) {
        rowData.push(dataTable.getValue(rowIdx, colIdx));
      }
      rows.push(rowData);
    }
    var newTB = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    newTB.addColumn('string', dataTable.getColumnLabel(0));
    newTB.addRows(dataTable.getNumberOfColumns() - 1);
    var colIdx = 1;
    for (var idx = 0; idx < (dataTable.getNumberOfColumns() - 1); idx++) {
      var colLabel = dataTable.getColumnLabel(colIdx);
      newTB.setValue(idx, 0, colLabel);
      colIdx++;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var rowData = rows[i];
      console.log(rowData[0]);
      newTB.addColumn('number', rowData[0]); //assuming the first one is always a header
      var localRowIdx = 0;

      for (var j = 1; j < rowData.length; j++) {
        newTB.setValue(localRowIdx, (i + 1), rowData[j]);
        localRowIdx++;
      }
    }
    return newTB;
  }

  function createObject(ID, sheet, GID, datatable, graphtype, rotated) {
    // Create the data objects and push them to the graphArray array 
    graphArray.push({
      ID: ID,
      sheet: sheet,
      GID: GID,
      datatable: datatable,
      graphtype: graphtype,
      rotated: rotated,
    });
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are looking for 'ready' event. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#the-ready-event

Comment: I think you're right. Something quick and dirty that might work:

I can easily count how many times the draw function is called. 

I can also change the ready event listener at https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events to an anonymous function and count how many times its triggered.

From 

'google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart, 'ready', myReadyHandler);'

to 

'google.visualization.events.addListener(tableChart, 'ready', function () {
  isloaded++}); '

and wait until the variables are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned what I was trying to do, which was to step through a list of various chart types to see what would be the best for what I wanted to display.

One of the things I wanted to look at was to create PNGs of the various charts. But, I ran foul of the "ready" event handlers again.

Just before I drew the charts I used

google.visualization.events.addListener(theGraphs, 'ready', function() {
        document.getElementById(imgLink).innerHTML = 'Printable Graph';
          });

but I was getting "Cannot read property 'getImageURI' of null" errors.

Presumably because of the loop the drawing of these graphs is in, it was running too fast for the event handler to catch?

I tried removing the event handler after the drawing of the charts using

google.visualization.events.removeListener(theGraphs);

and even

google.visualization.events.removeAllListeners(theGraphs);

I had thought of doing something like trying to count the number of times the event was triggered and comparing that to the number of times the function was called but went for a simpler, but probably not the best method, of adding  a setTimeout function.

setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById(imgLink).innerHTML = 'Printable Graph';
    }, 100);
    theGraphs.draw();

Probably not the most elegant solution, but the delay of just 1/10 of a second made the problems I've been having go away.

https://jsfiddle.net/brisray/z49jw264/706/

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById(imgLink).innerHTML = '<a target="_blank" href="' + theGraphs.getChart().getImageURI() + '">Printable Graph</a>';
}, 100);
theGraphs.draw();
```